# jQuery ajax post works on console but not from the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick

I can't find the answer from any searching I've done.

I have a simple button using an anchor tag in HTML:

```
<a id="beginUpload" href='/upload' class='button-style'>Upload</a>
```

The data is generated from an input element on the HTML with id 'file'.

My jQuery method is as follows:

```
$("#beginUpload").click(function () {
    var data = {
        mimeType : document.getElementById('file').files[0].type,
        fileSize : document.getElementById('file').files[0].size
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/post_asset/',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

When I run the contents of the click function (after first inputing a file) - it returns my expected response which is something like this:

```
Object {success: true, upload_url: "http://my_url", id: 12, mime_type: "audio/mp3", size: "52981888"}
```

However, when I run this code using the button, I get an error with an empty errorResponse text as follows:

```
Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you must send data in json format.Please try using this:  data: JSON.stringify(data).

Comment: I tried that @AlexandruMihai - no joy

Comment: try adding return false to the click handler, or update the href attribute to # instead of '/upload'

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prevent the default behavior of your link `a` (redirect to `/upload`) using `e.preventDefault()` :

```
$("#beginUpload").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //...Your code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the hyperlink, you need to prevent from posting by using something like:

```
$("#beginUpload").click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                mimeType : document.getElementById('file').files[0].type,
                fileSize : document.getElementById('file').files[0].size
            };
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/post_asset/',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Or you need to return false from the onclick handler.